# Delete 0 in front of numbers like 06, 07, etc

Tags: python

The column of pandas DataFrame contains values like:

```
d = {'Col1' : pd.Series(['07','','10','06']),'Col2' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])}
```

I want to delete 0 in front of some integers, i.e. 07->7, 06->6, while 10 is ok.
How can I do it (including the processing of empty cels)?

I tried this code, but it gives an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Comment: Add a sample of your df

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Done

Comment: I see you removed `nan`, do you have nan or was that supposed to represent an empty string? Also what should happen for an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int()` function doesn't work on empty strings, but you can easily fix it by having a fallback in case the value is falsy (and empty strings are indeed falsy):

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: int(x or 0))
```

`int(x)` will be called when the value is non empty, and `int(0)` when it is (assuming you want zeros in place of empty values).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the empty string and set astype to int:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace('', 0).astype(int)
```

Which for larger amounts of data would be faster: